# Valid parenthesis Matching in MSO

Tags: regular-languages, logic

What is the Monodic Second Order formula that encodes all binary strings that represent a valid parenthesis matching ? By this I mean 1s represent '(' and 0s represent ')' and at every position, number of 1s in the prefix is greater than or equal to the number of 0s .

Can someone tell me how to proceed ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you possibly formalize the question more rigorously, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The words in the language are formed using 0s and 1s . At every position, number of 1s in the prefix is greater than or equal to the number of 0s .
For Example,
1100 is a valid word but 1001 is not.

Comment: I also want to capture the fact that the total number of ones and zeros in the word are the same

Comment: Standard MSO logic on strings define the regular languages, so you have to explain what predicates you are allowed to use?